# find the Jordan form and $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = J$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

Consider the matrix $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} -11&0&-9\\32&1&24\\16&0&13 \end{array}\right)$$

I want to find the Jordan form of $A$, **with $1$-s at the bottom** and the jordan basis, which is $P$ columns such that $P^{-1}AP = J$.

I evaluated the charechteristic polynomial which is $f_A(x) = -(x-1)^3$. So we have one eigenvalue which is $\lambda =1$.

Now,

$$A-I = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} -12&0&-9\\32&0&24\\16&0&12 \end{array}\right)$$
$$\ker (A-I) = \text{span}\{(0,1,0),(1,0,3/4)\}$$
$$\ker (A-I)^2 =\mathbb{R}^3$$

As I understand I need to find a vector, $v_3$ such that $\ker (A-I) \cup v_3 = \ker (A-I)^2 = \mathbb{R}^3$.

Then, $$v_2 = (A-I)v_3 \\ v_1 = (A-I)v_2$$

And we (suppose to) get $P = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ such that $P^{-1}AP = J$.

I chose $v_3 = (1,0,0)$, but it doesn't work, and for the matter of fact I'm confused by all this.

I'd be glad if you could explain to me how to correct this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you only need the Jordan form you don't need the transformation matrixies.  From $\dim(Ker(A-I))= 2$, you already know that there are two blocks for the eigenvalue, thus the form of $J$ is already distinct

Comment: I do need to find $P$. Let me edit my question

Comment: Your formula for $v_1$ is not correct. You have to choose $v_1 \in Ker(A-I)$ such that it is linear independent to $v_2$.

Comment: Your $v_3$ and $v_2$, on the other hand, work perfectly well.

Comment: Your formula would only apply if you go down one more dimension, if you know what I mean. So if $v_3 \in Ker(A-I)^3$ then $v_2 = (A-I) v_3$ and  $v_1 = (A-I)^2 v_3 = (A-I) v_2$

Comment: @john your last comment doesn't work for this $A$.  That only works for a single $3 \times 3$ Jordan block.

Comment: I posted a full algorithm for calculating the Jordanform [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358482/computation-of-transformation-matrix-for-jordan-normal-form-how-to-choose-eigen/1358706#1358706). But this is probably even more confusing for you.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes of course I'm taking about the general approach, sorry if that was unclear. Though i think you mean for 3 Jordan blocks?

Comment: @john, Omnomnomnom  - Could you give the general algorithm in a couple of (readable) sentences please? Yeah I am still confuse a bit.

Comment: Sorry this is the best I can do, I tried making it a short and comprehensible as possible. Just do some more examples and I guarantee you will pick up on it.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of the right ingredients here. Let's put them together by  following the algorithm described by Stefan Friedl [here](http://math.rice.edu/~friedl/math355_fall04/Jordan.pdf).

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
\chi_A(t)=-(t-1)^3
$$
so the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda=1$ with algebraic multiplicity $m=3$. Note that
\begin{align*}
A-I&=\begin{bmatrix}-12&0&-9\\ 32&0&24\\16&0&12\end{bmatrix}&
(A-I)^2&=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
so $\DeclareMathOperator{null}{null}$
\begin{align*}
\dim\null(A-I) &= 2 & \dim\null(A-I)^2&=3
\end{align*}
We then compute the numbers
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= \dim\null(A-I) & d_2 &= \dim\null(A-I)^2-\dim\null(A-I) \\
&= 2 & &= 3-2 \\
&&&= 1
\end{align*}
so we must fill the boxes
$$
\begin{matrix}
\Box & \Box \\
\Box
\end{matrix}
$$
with vectors. Note that $u=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\end{bmatrix}^\top$ satisfies $u\in\null(A-I)^2$ but $u\notin\null(A-I)$. Put 
$$
v=(A-I)u=\begin{bmatrix}-12\\32\\16\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the diagram takes the form
$$
\begin{matrix}
v & \Box \\
u
\end{matrix}
$$
Since $w=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\end{bmatrix}^\top$ is linearly independent from $v$ we complete the Jordan basis $\{u,v,w\}$. Finally, put
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}
-12 & 1 & 0 \\
32 & 0 & 1 \\
16 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and note that the Jordan form of $A$ is
$$
J=P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, if we want the $1$'s on the superdiagonal to be on the subdiagonal, we need only reverse the order of the columns of $P$. Indeed, putting
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-12\\ 1 & 0 & 32\\ 0&0&16\end{bmatrix}
$$
gives
$$
Q^{-1}AQ=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: How can you convert the process described so I won't need to find the inverse?

Comment: @jmiller I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Oh never mind, thanks anway.

Answer (score 2):

As $\ker(A-I)^2=\mathbf R^3$, and $\dim\ker (A-I)=2$, all you have to do is to take a vector $v_1\in \ker(A-I)^2\smallsetminus\ker (A-I)$. Then $v_2=(A-I)v_1$ is a non-zero vector of the eigenspace ; you can complete this vector in a basis of the eigenspace.

As the equation of the eigenspace is $4x+3y=0$, we can take $e_1={}^{\mathrm t }(-1,0,1)$. Then $e_2=(A-I)e_1={}^{\mathrm t}(3,-8,-4)$. Complete the basis with, say $e_3={}^{\mathrm t}(0,1,0)$. In this basis, by construction the matrix of the endomorphism and the change of basis matrix are:
$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}, \quad P=\begin{bmatrix}-1&3&0\\0&-8&1\\1&-4&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Saying that 1 is an eigenvalue for matrix $A$ means that there exist non-zero vectors, $v$, such that $Av= v$ or $(A- I)v= 0$.

Here, that means $$\begin{bmatrix}-12 & 0 & -9 \\ 32 & 0 & 24 \\ 16 & 0 & 12\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-12x- 9z \\ 32x+ 24z \\ 16x+ 12z \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

You basically have that. Now note that this gives you the three equations $$-12x- 9z= 0,$$ $$32x+ 24z= 0,$$ and $$16x+ 12z= 0.$$  From the first equation, $9z= -12x$ so $z= (-12/9)x= (-4/3)x.$  Setting $z= (-4/3)x$ in the second and third equations gives $$32x+ 24(-4/3)x= 32x- 32x= 0$$ and $$16x+ 12z= 16x+ 12(-4/3)x= 16x- 16x= 0.$$
That is, for any value of $x, z= (-4/3)x$ will satisfy all those equations.  Since $y$ did not enter into this, $y$ can be anything.  That is, the eigenvectors must be of the  form $$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ (-4/3)x \end{pmatrix}= x\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -4/3\end{pmatrix}+ y\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

We can use $\begin{pmatrix}3\\ 0\\ -4\end{pmatrix}=3\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ -4/3\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ form a basis for the Eigen space.  since that is a two dimensional subspace, the "Jordan Normal Form" will be of the form $$J= \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$ and we can form the matrix $$P^{-1}$$ using the vectors $$\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 0\\ -4\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$ as columns.

Comment: Your answer needs formatting + clarification.

Comment: use `$$` and `$$`, not `[tex]` and `[/tex]`

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts need heavy editing